# How can I get sender email address while using zend imap

Tags: zend-framework, email, gmail, imap, sender

I have uploaded the whole screenshot of the mail which is sent to my gmail id. But fetch at my website using zend imap.

here I am not able to figure out the exact sender email address header.

as you can see I am getting sender name not email in 'From' Header.

Any Ideas?

This is Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Maybe you should post screenshot elsewhere and link to it. Currently it's kinda useless.

Comment: just for giggles did you try $message->getHeaders(), returns all headers as an array.

Comment: @RockyFord , why useless it is visible.

and I have already useed getHeaders. still there is no solution !!!

Comment: I don't know what it looks like to you, but on my end it's unreadable.

Comment: @RockyFord right click on image open in new tab. on image zoom option is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$header = imap_rfc822_parse_headers($storage->getRawHeader($email_id));
$from_email = $header->from[0]->mailbox . "@" . $header->from[0]->host;
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

ot looks like the problem may be Yahoo is not providing a classic address in the header it's providing a user number as demonstrated  by:

```
->recieved[7];
```

and at :

```
->message-id;
```

these both reference what appears to be the sender (or at least the first leg in yahoo)
`web122216.mail.ne1.yahoo.com`.

This is your sender (at least it appears as such). You may have to pound on the yahoo api to get better results for an actual e-mail address.

...Good Luck

Comment: Thanx For the Reply Bro !

But the sender can be anyone, mail can be from yahoo , gmail , hotmail ..... 
and in all mails, the reply is like above only -- from where I can not fetch sender id !! :|